# JavaScript - Execute Function Based on Sent Object Property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects. These objects have a bunch of cost properties

```
var myArray = 
[
{"ID": "1"; "CostA": 200, "CostB": 3000, "CostC": 900},
{"ID": "1"; "CostA": 150, "CostB": 2500, "CostC": 800},
{"ID": "1"; "CostA": 210, "CostB": 4000, "CostC": 600}
]
```

Based on some user action, I'd like to pass a function like this,

```
function deteremineCosts(myArray, CostPassed)
```

CostPassed will be one of the cost properties in the object - CostA, CostB, or CostC.

Is there a way to get an object's value by doing something like `myArray[0].CostPassed`?

I realize I can also just do the following (and I'd rather not because the list of cost properties is huge) -

```
if (CostPassed = "CostC")
{
   var someCost = myArray[0].CostC;
}
```

I believe jQuery `.each` will be able to get a key and value from an object but I'm running into issue getting the property names (not just values) out of an array of objects.

Answer (score 3):

After awaring that

```
obj['foo']
```

is equivalent to (if `foo` is a valid identifier)

```
obj.foo
```

You can simply use

```
var cost = myArray[0][CostPassed];
```

Comment: Ahh of course duh, I totally forgot you could pass in a variable like that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple for loop to achieve this:

```
for(var name in obj){
   console.log(name); // this will output field name, not the value
   console.log(obj[name]); //this will output the value;
}
```